# Finding differential equation with three constants

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation of

$$y = Ae^{ax} + Be^{bx} + Ce^{cx}$$ where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are constants.

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. Probably that is why someone voted to close the question. They ought to explain that here in comments when they do that, but usually they don't. You can ask for help understanding a homework problem or you can say at what point you got stuck on a problem.

Comment: I see $6$ constants.

Comment: What do you know about linear differential equations which have as solutions constant multiples of one or two exponentials?

Comment: @MyGlasses: the six-constants problem is much more challenging ! For the term $Ae^{ax}$ alone, the equation would be $yy''=y'^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that a single exponential term obeys a linear equation of the first order where the exponential coefficient is the root of the characteristic equation.

$$(Ae^{ax})'=Aae^{ax}$$ or $$y'-ay=0.$$

Using the differential operator,

$$(D-a)y=0.$$

Now if you apply the same factor to another exponential,

$$(D-a)Be^{bx}=Bbe^{bx}-ae^{bx}=B'e^{bx},$$ the exponential remains unchanged (to a constant factor).

Hence

$$(D-a)(D-b)(D-c)y$$ will cancel out all three exponentials.

Comment: Is not $(D-a)(D-b)(D-c)y=0$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses: no, I am referring to the LHS expression, which cancels out the exponential. It would make no sense to say that the equation does.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is obtaining $y'$, $y''$ and $y'''$ so with $y$ we have four equations with three constants, then deleting these Constants gives us
$$y'''-(a+b+c)y''+(ab+bc+ca)y'-abcy=0$$